# Java Converting ByteArray into Image

Tags: java, image, arrays

I'm reading a file that has an array of bytes. I downloaded the Apache Commons IO library to use the FileUtils' method readFileToByteArray

```
File file = new File("/home/username/array.txt");
FileUtils fu = new FileUtils();
byte[] array = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
```

I want to convert the array of bytes to an Image.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("gif");

ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
Object source = bis;

ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);

reader.setInput(iis, true);
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

Image image = reader.read(0, param); // this line is the problem
```

When the code goes to the referred line, it throws an Exception saying

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unexpected block type 128!
```

I don't know what this exception means, therefore, I don't know how to fix it.
Any further information that could be helpful just need to be requested.

Thanks

Comment: You can do all of the above with a single line of code: `Image image = ImageIO.read(file);`  That will eliminate any issues with byte arrays and will remove your dependency on an external library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/LayeredPaneDemoProject/src/components/images/dukeWaveRed.gif) file and it works fine.

What's the format of your `array.txt`? `readFileToByteArray()` expects a binary format, and your image reader will further expect it to be a GIF file.

Comment: How did you get the byteArray of it? Maybe what I'm getting isn't a byteArray.

Comment: Well, I suppose the question is, what does your file look like e.g. if  opened in an editor. The `.txt` is worrying. If your file looks like `123 22 55 98...`, then you'll need to parse the values e.g. with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Well, the only string readable is `GIF89a`. The rest is unreadable by any means.

Comment: Well, in that case it _should_ work. If you change the file extension to `.gif` and double-click it in your file browser, does it open normally? If not, it's not impossible your image file is corrupt.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't open it. I'll check my methods of getting the bytearray than come back to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `byte[]` you can use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to write it to BufferedImage.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(array));
ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "gif", new File("c:/test.gif"));
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but the result was the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

That code means the reader couldn't decipher the metadata on the image file.  Make sure the right file is getting read and it's well formed. Or it may be expecting a different file type.

Comment: How can I assure the file is well formed?

Comment: See if that image file can be opened by another program. Preferably one that's not overly forgiving or one that allows you to inspect the metadata.

Comment: Actually, I don't have the image. What I have is a txt file with the data information written inside.

Comment: As I and the other responders have observed, we think the problem lies in the data file.  Your code clip implies a text file, the reader expects a binary file.  If you can open it up and read numbers, then it's, at best, an ASCII encoded file that will need to be converted back to binary before the Imagereader can consume it.

Comment: No. As I answered on Vlad's post, I don't view numbers, only a bunch of interrogation marks and some letters and numbers mixed up.

Comment: Well, assuming that it is a valid GIF file, you can look at the source code to the GIFImageReader here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/imageio/plugins/gif/GIFImageReader.java.html and you can walk through the execution with some of your data file to see where you go.

Answer (score 0):

without byte[] i feel this will be good for multipart file transfer,for this we need apache common jar files

```
    final FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Dir\\"+ request.getParameter("imageName") + ".jpg");
        IOUtils.copy(request.getPart("file").getInputStream(), output);
        output.close();
```